# How to convert lead into account with custom fields in lead screen

Tags: apex, salesforce-classic

I have a problem, I need to convert the direct lead, when I click on the convert button it opens a window to fill in some data like, opportunity name, task, and reminder.

[image: Lead Convert Default]

I created these fields in the lead screen so that it is populated before and when I click on the button, convert the conversion to be direct without the default screen, I will post some images of how I want

[image: Custom Fields in Lead Screen]

I currently have a button to convert with the following code

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/apex.js")}

var id = '{!Lead.Id}';

var link = sforce.apex.execute('BotaoJavaScript', 'criarLead', {leadId:id}); 

window.location.href = link;
```

this button refers to this apex class

```
Global without sharing class BotaoJavaScript {

    webservice static string criarLead(Id leadId){
        System.debug('Id Lead: ' + leadId);
        String link = '/{IdAcc}';
        LeadDAO leadDAO = new LeadDAO();
        Lead lead = leadDAO.getLeadById(leadId);


        Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(leadId);

        LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
        lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
        lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(String.isEmpty(lead.Name));

        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
        System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());

        }
        System.debug(JSON.serialize(lc));
        link = link.replace('{IdAcc}', lc.getAccountId());

        System.debug('Link: ' + link );
        return link;
    }
}
```

the lead is converted but all fields get null, I made a debug serialize and I had this return from the Developer Console

> 16:11:43:652 USER_DEBUG
>   [46]|DEBUG|{"accountId":null,"accountRecord":null,"bypassAccountDedupeCheck":null,"bypassContactDedupeCheck":null,"contactId":null,"contactRecord":null,"convertedStatus":"Qualificado","doNotCreateOpportunity":true,"leadId":"00Q1F000002dXM1","opportunityId":null,"opportunityName":null,"opportunityRecord":null,"overwriteLeadSource":false,"ownerId":null,"sendNotificationEmail":false}

Can someone help me with how to make this change?